# How can I color the left half of the robe?

Tags: materials, color, mirror

I'm trying to color the left half of my robes just like my reference image. However, I can't seem to do so since my robe is mirrored. Is there any way for me to apply my colors without re doing the entire robe? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Apply the mirror Modifier, which would then give you a complete mesh that has both left and right sides, and apply the "uncolored" material, and also add a second material "colored". You would then want to select all the faces on the left (?) side of the mesh and create a "left side" vertex group where you could Apply the "colored" material. You might first duplicate the robe to keep a backup of the original half robe with Mirror Modifier, should you need access to this in the future.

[image]

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Thank you. ^_^